# VerticalSplitPanel doesn't show widgets in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

This is some very simple code that I'm using to try showing a VerticalSplitPanel, but the widgets I add don't show. The divider thing of VerticalSplitPanels does show however the widgets I add don't.

Code:

```
public class MyView extends Composite
{
    private VerticalSplitPanel mainPanel=new VerticalSplitPanel();

    public CountryFilterView()
    {               

        mainPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
        mainPanel.setSplitPosition("50%");
        // Add some content
        String randomText = "This is some text to show how the contents on either "
            + "side of the splitter flow.   "
            + "This is some text to show how the contents on either "
            + "side of the splitter flow.   "
            + "This is some text to show how the contents on either "
            + "side of the splitter flow.   ";
        mainPanel.setTopWidget(new HTML(randomText));
        mainPanel.setBottomWidget(new HTML(randomText));
        initWidget(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is VerticalPanel just very annoyingly buggy?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code (with a small tweak to fix compile error) and it is displaying both widgets.  I have tried this in GWT 2.0.

Here is the code I used that is working.  Notice the Constructor name difference.

```
public class MyView extends Composite
{
    private VerticalSplitPanel mainPanel=new VerticalSplitPanel();

    public MyView()
    {                           

        mainPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
        mainPanel.setSplitPosition("50%");
        // Add some content
        String randomText = "This is some text to show how the contents on either "
            + "side of the splitter flow.   "
            + "This is some text to show how the contents on either "
            + "side of the splitter flow.   "
            + "This is some text to show how the contents on either "
            + "side of the splitter flow.   ";
        mainPanel.setTopWidget(new HTML(randomText));
        mainPanel.setBottomWidget(new HTML(randomText));
        initWidget(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

And here is how i invoked it.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(new MyView());
}
```

Comment: they may have fixed it in the new version